# Where to store text input state with presentational and container components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Using the presentational and container components that [Dan Abramov has previously discussed](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) , I have a presentational component which has an input and button and a container component which handles the text given from the input and dispatches an event when the select button is pressed.

Presentational Component:

```
import React from 'react'

const NavBar = ({ onClick, handleChange }) => {
    return (
        <div className="NavBar">         
            <input onChange={handleChange} />
            <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>Search</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

Container Component:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import {requestStat} from '../../stats/actions/StatsAction'

// meh, not a big fan of this, but I think it's the right compromise for handling the textinput.
let textInput

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    handleChange: (e) => textInput = e.target.value,
    onClick : (e) => handleSelectedTab(dispatch)    
})

const handleSelectedTab = (dispatch) => {
    if (textInput != null && textInput != "") {
        dispatch(requestStat(textInput))
    }
}

const NavBarContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar)
```

I'm wondering where it's best to store the input string?

In my current solution I'm storing this state as in the textInput variable on the container component - is this the best place for it with this current set-up?

I've previously stored this value as a variable in the presentational component, which then passed the value to the container when submit was pressed, but this didn't feel quite right. The advantage that I get with storing the input value in the container is that the presentational component makes no assumptions of what to do with the input text, other than to run the handleChange callback and having this callback be injected into the presentational component makes for a natural unit test on this behaviour:

```
export default NavBarContainer

import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import Navbar from './Navbar'


describe('NavBar', () =>{

    it ('run callback when input changed, setting value to true', () => {

        let change = false
        const handleChange = () => { change = true; }

        const props = { handleChange }
        const component = shallow(<Navbar {...props} />)

        expect(change).toBe(false)

        const formGroup = component.find('input')
        formGroup.simulate('change')

        expect(change).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

Any thoughts / best practises or advice would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

To clarify; I already have a redux store and actions in place, but it seems overkill to be updating the store every time someone types a character into the input field.

I also don't need to store this value once the user hits submit, as the event gets picked up by a saga, which then in turn uses it to get data from a web server, the results of which go into the redux store via a reducer.

**Edit 2:**

I'd also rather not use the component state as updating it will cause re-rendering and with its async nature I can't easily trust that it's been updated by the time the user hits the button.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it most of depend on your use case like what exactly you want your component to do.

For example if your component have just input and one button then it is better to keep its input in container. Imagine this, if you keep your text input handler in this component itself and only pass the button click handler then it might work for now but in future what if you want to handle the input text before the user click the button. For example you might want to limit the input character in this input box later and then you might have to do some modification in the component.

One more example can be like suppose you want to make component which do some processing on input value when button is pressed like email validation. At that time it make sense to keep the input value in the component itself. So every time button is pressed then validate the email id and then only call the button handler passed to it as prop. And this becomes an email validator component of your application.

Though it is just a rough example but it is enough to clarify my point i think. Actually the component should be flexible enough such that they can be used as much as possible.

Comment: A value in the store is always available. You can get and manipulate the value to do anything you want at any time. If you have no need for the value of the input once the component is unmounted, then I would keep it in container state. Otherwise I'd put it in the store.

Comment: Thats fine but the question says about the presentational component and presentaional component should be unaware of redux state and should not communicate directly with redux state.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly why I'm keeping the textInput in the container - so that the presentation is more flexible and it means that if certain conditions were met on the textInput (such as at length) then I could easily track this and dispatch an event from the container, all whilst keeping the presentation light weight. Would you take a different approach to having the 'let textInput'? In an immutable project it doesn't feel great to be doing this mutation..

Answer (score 0):

You're using redux and already connecting your component. You should store it in your redux `store` and add a `mapStateToProps` to your `connect()` method.

```
mapStateToProps = ( state ) = > {
    return {
        inutText: state.inputText
    }
}

const NavBarContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar);
```

Then just make a reducer for your NavBar and an action to handle the change.

Edit: To address your comment;

You're going to have to update something every time someone types a character. It's a very light weight module and the update is very fast. Even though you're *you're returning the entire state*, you're really only updating that one property. Considering you don't mutate state in redux, all of the other properties just point to the same place in memory. You're just assigning a pointer.

EDIT #2:

A value in the store is always available. You can get and manipulate the value to do anything you want at any time. If you have no need for the value of the input once the component is unmounted, then I would keep it in container state. Otherwise I'd put it in the store.

And remember, a value in the store can be used to hydrateState on navigation if a user navigates away you could repopulate the value for them if it is in the store.

If you want to handle the state inside a component, I would do it like this.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import {requestStat} from '../../stats/actions/StatsAction';

class navBar extends PureComponent {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        this.state = {
            textInput: props.textInput || ""
        }

        this.handleSelectedTab = this.handleSelectedTab.bind( this );
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind( this );
    }

    handleSelectedTab() {
        // I don't see where you use this

        // dispatch is available here.
        // this.props.dispatch
    }

    handleChange( e ) {
        // handle change
    }

    render() {
        const { textInput } = this.state;
        return (
            <NavBar onClick={ this.handleSelectedTab } handleChange={ this.handleChange } value={ textInput } />
        );
    }
}

const NavBarContainer = connect()(navBar);

export default NavBarContainer;
```

The way you have it would not allow for more than one component. They would step on each other.

Comment: To clarify; I already have a redux store and actions in place, but it seems overkill to be updating the store every time someone types a character into the input field, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, it's the mutation that I've got the problem with, however this value feels like it's component state rather than application state until the user presses submit (something I've seen Dan talk about), which is why I'm a bit dubious about putting it into the redux store at this point (in truth the event is picked up by a saga and this value never even goes into the store, just the results from the saga).

Comment: What do you mean you have a problem with the mutation? Are you having trouble not mutating your data?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I don't like that I'm mutating the textInput value in the container, as the rest of my application is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a React application you could save it in the component's state, but for React with Redux the best thing to do is to save the state in the store provided by Redux.

To accomplish this you will need to set up some action creators and a reducer. Take a look at [TodoList example app](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) for an example of what I am talking about. Generally you would use an actions file to write simple functions that are passed as props to your presentational components through your container components.

UPDATED BASED ON COMMENTS:

You could use something like

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

class NavBar extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = { onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired }
    handleChange = (e) => this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
    onClick = (e) => this.props.onClick(this.state.inputValue)
    render(){
       return (
         <div className="NavBar">         
          <input onChange={handleChange} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>Search</button>
         </div>
       )
     }
}

export default NavBar
```

Comment: To clarify; I already have a redux store and actions in place, but it seems overkill to be updating the store every time someone types a character into the input field, don't you think?

Comment: Not at all, I do it all the time, it is what Redux was designed for.

Comment: But this feels like it's very much component state, rather than application state (which I've seen Dan talk about previously) - the application state only needs to know the value once the user hits submit, triggering loads of events just doesn't seem right to me at the input stage.

Comment: The only other option that I see is to create a smarter component that would allow you to save the state in the component using this.setState({key: value})

Comment: As opposed to the method I've gone with above? I fear that would just add needless complexity to both the component and testing it, especially with the async nature of setState.

Comment: I have encountered few problems with this approach and testing, you just test it as normal. 
Really a component test for this component should only really test that the input received by the onClick function prop is what is expected which means that how you store the value of the input itself shouldn't make any difference. I don't see you needing to test that an html input works...

Comment: I simplified it for this question, but in my project I'm not using an html input and am using a component, but yeah I get the argument for not needing to test at this level. I like the updated example, but doesn't that run into potential async problems that react state has where you can't guarantee that the component state has not being updated before the user hits submit? Also doesn't updating the state cause this to get rendered, so would cause a lot of re-rendering?

Comment: Yes updating the state would cause it to re-render, and I guess there is the potential for an async problem but I have never experienced that with components that are far larger and more complicated than this. If the re-rendering causes an issue for you, you could refactor your component to be a collection of smaller components and then set the state on the smallest component possible so that the re-render isn't rendering a complicated page.

Comment: Thanks Robert, it's interesting to hear these ideas! To be honest I think I prefer the solution in my original post - more components for the sake of getting around this issue adds complexity and has the side effect of triggering more rendering. Yes, I'm mutating data in the container which I'd rather not do, but it's simple to understand.